# Python Pandas - Can you use .loc and ignore indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace a string found in a column with

```
file1_backup_df.loc[file1_backup_df['CustName'].str.contains('bbb', case=False), 'CustomerName'] = 'Big Boy Booty'
```

Now the above works on a single dataframe (file1_backup_df). But I am combining dataframes like this;

```
frames = [add_backup_name(), file1_backup_df]
final_df = pd.concat(frames)
```

I'd like to perform the very first line of code on `final_df`. But I can't.

It grumbles about

```
__setitem__
indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)`.

ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN value
```

Is there a way to replace strings in a column of my combined df?

I tried this but no go;

```
pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```

**EDIT**

Looks like this may have done it. Testing.

[https://www.statology.org/cannot-mask-with-non-boolean-array-containing-na-nan-values/#:~:text=2022%20by%20Zach-,How%20to%20Fix%3A%20ValueError%3A%20Cannot%20mask%20with%20non%2Dboolean,array%20containing%20NA%20%2F%20NaN%20values&text=This%20error%20usually%20occurs%20when,searching%20in%20has%20NaN%20values](https://www.statology.org/cannot-mask-with-non-boolean-array-containing-na-nan-values/#:%7E:text=2022%20by%20Zach-,How%20to%20Fix%3A%20ValueError%3A%20Cannot%20mask%20with%20non%2Dboolean,array%20containing%20NA%20%2F%20NaN%20values&text=This%20error%20usually%20occurs%20when,searching%20in%20has%20NaN%20values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the column `CustomerName` holds some `NaN` values, so you need to set `na=False` in [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) :

Try this :

```
final_df.loc[final_df['CustName'].str.contains('bbb', case=False, na=False), 'CustomerName'] = 'Big Boy Booty'
```

Comment: It was that plus this `final_df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)`.